# How to change the color of an OpenCV Viz::WMesh object?

Tags: c++, opencv, 3d, visualization

I have a `viz::WMesh` object, representing a surface, created using its constructor:

```
WMesh(InputArray cloud, InputArray polygons, InputArray colors);
```

How can I change the array of colors used by the mesh to change its appearance?

The only member function available is `viz::Widget2D::setColor(const Color& color)` but it sets the same color for all the mesh's polygons.
I guess that using the `WidgetAccessor` class it is possible to do the task, but since I'm new to vtk I'm searching for an easier solution.
(I'm using OpenCV 3.0 beta)

I know that a straightforward solution is to create another Mesh with the new set of colors and use `Viz3D::showWidget()` to replace the old mesh, but this solution is too slow since the surface has about 2 millions of polygons.